# PCF8574 and OLED SSD1306 I2C conflict

Tags: i2c, esp8266, oled, expander

I have a ESP12 module which is connected to multiple I2C devices such as an 24C08 EEPROM, DS1307 RTC and a PC8574 expander.
Everything works fine until I decided to add an OLED module to this setup. After adding this module, I2C bus stopped working and no devices were found by the ESP. I tried to remove every component one by one to pinpoint the conflicting component. It seems when I remove the PCF8574 IC (or OLED module), every other component works fine. I tried to reconnect the expander (and OLED) while the circuit is running and then the ESP can detect every component on the bus including the added one!
I tried to change I2C pull-up resistors but no luck. I use Adafruit OLED library for display and [this](https://github.com/xreef/PCF8574_library/blob/master/PCF8574.h) for expander. Both libraries use proper methods to start and end transmission.
Is it a know issue with these two devices? I couldn't find anything on the Internet.
Are there symptoms related to any known issues?

Comment: What is the I2C address of the PCF8574 and OLED module? It might be a clash in I2C addresses.

Comment: Mehdi - Do you have an oscilloscope? If so, have you looked at (a) the quality (rise/fall time & general shape) of the I2C signals? (b) the I2C bus behaviour, comparing the working and failing configurations? Just to be clear, I expect that you are not adding those *components*, but you are adding pre-made PCB modules, which contain those components, as well as additional I2C pull-up resistors and other parts. Is that correct?

Comment: @PeterKarlsen There is no conflict in addresses. I checked it.

Comment: @SamGibson I have a DSO138 oscilloscope. I don't know if it is good for this purpose but I will check. Just RTC and EEPROM components are on a module (TinyRTC).

Comment: @MehdiMaazi - "*I have a DSO138 oscilloscope*" So please capture traces showing the I2C bus shape in working/non-working configurations; and the simplest test case you can make which has one step between working and not working (the exact steps involving expander and OLED are not clear to me, but you know them). Look for differences between the working and non-working configs. Edit the question and add those scope traces (carefully labelled!) & your analysis into the question. Also add photos of your actual hardware, so we can see things like length of I2C wires, breadboard layout etc. Thanks.

Comment: @SamGibson I will do as you instructed me. This is what I really wanted. To teach me how to debug such problems (and not this particular issue). And you talk so friendly! I appreciate that!

Comment: From each board, figure out if it has pull-up resistors, and if it has, what resistance they are, and to what supply voltage. Add the info to your question. Add also links to schematics of each board you have. Usually 5V powered devices need pull-ups to 5V, and 3.3V powered devices need pull-ups to 3.3V, so they cannot be mixed unless bus level translators are used.